# JavaCV with android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk, javacv

i'm working on android app that create video from list of images using javacv i did all the following :

Follow the instructions on this page: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/

1. Go to File > New > Folder, select your project as parent folder, type "libs/armeabi" as Folder name, and click Finish.
2. Copy javacpp.jar and javacv.jar into the newly created "libs" folder.
3. Extract all the *.so files from javacv-android-arm.jar, opencv-2.4.8-android-arm.jar, and ffmpeg-2.1.1-android-arm.jar directly into the newly created "libs/armeabi" folder, without creating any of the subdirectories found in the JAR files.
4. Navigate to Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries and click "Add JARs...".
5. Select both javacpp.jar and javacv.jar from the newly created "libs" folder.

i almost tried everything ,  i tried edit build.gradle file to compile with ffmpeg&opencv&javacv&jacacpp, it should contain:

i already used android ndk with simple example and it's working , but i have no idea how to make to work with javacv , i don't know how i can implement new functions like this in my activity or in test.c?

also included the c library in my activity

but i always get this error : UnsatisfiedLinkError

Comment: You simply need to import the jars onto your project. That's all you need to do if you are using JavaCV. Its a Java wrapper for OpenCv, so you do not need NDK.

Comment: thanks for your reply ,i did add the javacv and javacpp in the lib folder but i keep get the same error also i put the .so file in libs/armbie but the same

Answer (score 1):

thanks for reply of user phOb I managed to include JavaCV to my Android Studio Project and to resolve the error I got like Marcel

1. In my project module named **app** in the folder **app/src/main** I created folder **jniLibs** and moved there folder **armeabi** with all *.so files I extracted from ffmpeg-android-arm.jar and opencv-android-arm.jar
2. In my build.gradle I added these lines to android section

   ```
   productFlavors {
   arm {
       ndk {
           abiFilter "armeabi"
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. In dependencies section I include these lines

   ```
   compile files('libs/ffmpeg.jar')
   compile files('libs/javacpp.jar')
   compile files('libs/javacv.jar')
   compile files('libs/opencv.jar')
   ```

That's all. Hope this will help someone else

Answer (score 0):

1. ffmpeg-2.1.1-android-arm.jar, 2. javacpp.jar, 3. javacv.jar, 4. javacv-android-arm.jar, 5. opencv-2.4.8-android-arm.jar. These are the only jars you need to add in your project.

Besides you need set up a sys Variable on your development machine.
This step is explained [here](http://vidhyadessai.wordpress.com/2011/12/14/settings-to-use-opencv-with-java/)

Just follow the steps for sys path setting, from this guide. Then simply import above mentioned jars into your project. It should be sufficient.

Comment: ffmpeg-2.1.1,ffmpeg-2.1.1,javacv-android-arm.jar is not added in the libs folder as jars but we copy the .so files into "libs/armeabi" right?

Comment: thanks , i followed this link , i had an error in missing .so files

Comment: did you set up system variable and install JavaCv?

follow steps 2-5 in the link, and then just add the jars which I have listed. It should work like charm!

Answer (score 0):

You're mentioning gradle in your question.
With gradle android-plugin (and Android Studio), by default you have to put your .so files inside `jniLibs` instead of `libs`.

That means you should extract all the .so files from -android-***.jar files into the folder corresponding to their target architecture: `jniLibs\armeabi` and `jniLibs\x86`.